# Animation does not work CSS

Tags: css, css-transitions, pseudo-element, webkit-transform

I am trying to add some animation for my CSS class
Here's code:

```
#primary_nav_wrap li a:hover:after {
  height: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  background-color: #23a298;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 96px;
  width: calc(100% - 15px);

  -webkit-transition: color 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: color 0.4s ease-out;
  -o-transition: color 0.4s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: color 0.4s ease-out;
  transition: color 0.4s ease-out;
}
```

Everything is fine, but this part does not work:

```
-webkit-transition: color 0.4s ease-out;
-moz-transition: color 0.4s ease-out;
-o-transition: color 0.4s ease-out;
-ms-transition: color 0.4s ease-out;
transition: color 0.4s ease-out;
```

Comment: I need detail your code. css, html

Comment: Add your HTML code, so that you could get help.    As per my knowledge you have to give transition to the parent element and give the properties you want to change in the child element.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/y7mkaq3b/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code to your `a:after`

```
#primary_nav_wrap li a:after {
  height: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 96px;
  width: calc(100% - 15px);
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.4s ease-out;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.4s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: background-color 0.4s ease-out;
  transition: background-color 0.4s ease-out;
}
```

You don't put the transition effect on the hover, also, you didn't mention which style should get the transition so I gave it to the `background-color`

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/7o2mw6ng/

Answer (score 1):

Try placing the transition on the element *without* the hover applied:

```
#primary_nav_wrap li a:after {
    -webkit-transition: color 0.4s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: color 0.4s ease-out;
    -o-transition: color 0.4s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: color 0.4s ease-out;
    transition: color 0.4s ease-out;
}
```

Edit: You're changing the colour on the `a` tag so you need to apply the transition there.

```
#primary_nav_wrap ul a {
    -webkit-transition: color 0.4s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: color 0.4s ease-out;
    -o-transition: color 0.4s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: color 0.4s ease-out;
    transition: color 0.4s ease-out;
}
```

[See jsfiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/sff0bank/)

Comment: Still same problem

Comment: Hmm. It's tricky to say where the issue is as we've only got one part of the code here. If you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) showing the problem I'm sure we can help. For example, your code doesn't show where `color` is applied?

Comment: @Nedvid have updated the answer to work based on your specific issue there.